# Is there are possibility to kill tmux process on server using timer?

Tags: tmux

I have `tmux` installed on a server for running `jupyter`. Fitting neural nets takes a lot of time, but server is public, so there is also a lack of resources.
I wonder if I could run my programs, estimate its running time roughly, then write a command like `tmux kill --time 5000`, where `5000` is the estimated runtime in seconds. That way, I do not borrow unused resources.

Comment: perhaps you want to use the timeout command.

Comment: @toppk you mean timeout for commands?

Comment: How do you run programs in `tmux`? The tmux server will exit when all commands started by `new-session`, `new-window`, `split-window` and such exit, unless some pane uses `remain-on-exit` or `exit-empty` is `off`. It's easy to run commands in tmux in a way so the tmux server exits automatically when it's no longer needed, unless some command doesn't exit by itself and has to be killed (killing manually may be simpler than building logic).

Answer (score 1):

I kind of found out it by myself.

To kill process you can use `sleep` command:

```
sleep <time in seconds> && tmux kill-session -t <session name>
```

or, if you need to kill all the `tmux` session, you simply can type:

```
sleep <time in seconds> && pkill tmux
```

**UPD**: Also, like was recommended from comments, one can use
 `timeout <time> tmux <command>`

Comment: As mentioned in comments, also try `timeout 5000 tmux some-command`. See `man timeout` on your system.

Comment: @Kusalananda, thanks, I will definitely try!

Comment: @Kusalananda In `timeout 5000 tmux some-command` the `tmux` being a child of `timeout` is always a tmux client. In some circumstances a forked descendant becomes a tmux server. Any tmux server survives disconnection of a client (after all this is one of the main features of tmux). IMO this means `timeout` cannot affect tmux server. My tests seem to support this.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Well, `tmux timeout 5000 some-command` then.

Comment: @Kusalananda `timeout` is not a valid command in `tmux`. My impression is you think `tmux something` is like `nohup something` or `sudo something`. Well, it's not.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I seem to have forgotten to include the `-c` option, which you could have pointed out yourself. `tmux -c 'timeout 5000 some-command'`.  You may have to tweak the other options to `timeout`, obviously, depending on what the command you're timing out is, and sort out quoting if needed, but that's the basics.

Answer (score 1):

`kill`ing the `tmux` server won't necessarily stop processes you run inside tmux. It seems, however, you want to kill `tmux` when presumably all the programs you have started in it are no more.

By default tmux server exits when all processes assigned to its panes exit. There is `remain-on-exit` you can use to keep a pane open and examine the results of its process that exited; but it seems you want to kill the server anyway, without reattaching and reviewing, so I don't think you use `remain-on-exit`. There is `exit-empty` that can be set to `off` to keep the server running without sessions, but you don't want this. It seems to me the default behavior is exactly what you want. All you need to do is to make sure the processes assigned to panes exit.

When you do `tmux new-session command1`, `command1` is the process assigned to the single pane in the single window in the newly created session. You can then `tmux new-window command2` and `tmux split-window command3` and so on. After `command1`, `command2`, `command3` (and others, if any) exit and there is no other session, the tmux server will exit.

Note if you create a session/window/pane with an interactive shell then the shell is the process that matters. `command4` started from the shell may exit, but the shell will remain, so the tmux server will remain. If you are used to running programs from interactive shells in tmux and you want to keep it this way, to make tmux exit as soon as it's not needed you should make sure each shell exits just after the task in it exits. In a shell inside tmux you can do

```
command4; exit
```

or even

```
command4; command5 && command6 | (command7; command8) | command9; exit
```

This way the shell will eventually exit, if only the commands exit. In case of a sole simple `command4` you can invoke

```
exec command4
```

to replace the shell with `command4`, so from now on `command4` is what matters to the tmux server.

One way or another make sure all the panes in all the windows in all the sessions will exit eventually. If you do this right then the tmux server will exit automatically after they all exit.

With this approach you don't need to estimate anything. The tmux server will last exactly for as long as it's needed and you don't risk killing it prematurely.

Again, all this is under assumption that any output to a terminal (pane) in this tmux is expendable. In your own answer I see you want to kill the session or the tmux server without checking anything.

Note my solution allows you to spawn a new session or a window or a pane if needed, anytime, without worrying about some old timer that no longer fits the new situation. Each pane will disappear exactly when it's not needed; the same for each window, each session and the entire tmux server.

The solution will not really work if some command assigned to a pane is meant to run indefinitely (i.e. until killed on demand). I think the question is not about such command though. But in case it is, remember that `command4` may be like `timeout 5000 actual_command4`.