# Cannot create 2 columns with TMUX

Tags: bash, tmux, kubernetes, tmuxinator

This seems create a bunch of rows with a single column. I am trying to create 2 columns, and then all the rows needed.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

(
  unset TMUX

  export session_uuid="$(uuidgen)"

  remove_tmux_session() {
    tmux kill-session -t "$session_uuid"
  }

  export -f remove_tmux_session

  trap remove_tmux_session TERM INT SIGINT SIGTERM

  echo "TMUX session id: $session_uuid"
  tmux new -d -s "$session_uuid"
  tmux set-option -g update-environment "remove_tmux_session session_uuid"

  # Run kubectl get pods and skip the header line
  kubectl get pods | tail -n +2 | while read -r line; do
      # Extract the first column (pod name)
      pod_name=$(echo "$line" | awk '{print $1}')

      # Run kubectl logs for each pod in a new tmux pane
      tmux split-window -v -t "$session_uuid" "kubectl logs '$pod_name' -f"
      tmux select-layout even-vertical

      # Create a new horizontal split for the second column
      tmux split-window -h -t "$session_uuid" "echo 'Second Column'"

      # Move to the next vertical pane in the new column
      tmux select-pane -t :.+

      # Create a new vertical split for the next row
      tmux split-window -v -t "$session_uuid" "echo 'Next Row'"

      # Move to the next horizontal pane in the new row
      tmux select-pane -t :.+

      # Repeat the process for additional rows/columns as needed
  done

  # Attach to the tmux session
  tmux attach-session -d -t "$session_uuid"
)
```

anyone know how to create 2 columns and then put each process inside a different row in the 2 column grid?

I am on Macos, Tmux version **3.3a**

Comment: Your description is confusing to me, but given your cmds `tmux split-window ...`, `tmux select-layout even-vertical ....` and `tmux select-pane ...` etc, it sounds self-describing. Do these cmds work from the basic cmd-line (without the `kubectl get pods ... | while ...` wrapper? One of the few times a graphic image could help with question? Or at least an ascii-art drawing? Is there another term? I think of columns being inside of terminal's border. Good luck.

Comment: `tmux split-window -h -t "$session_uuid" "echo 'Second Column'"` – A pane that only executes `echo` will exit immediately and be destroyed, unless `remain-on-exit` tmux option is `on` for it. Please confirm you set this option to `on` and the behavior I described is not a part of the problem.

Comment: ahh that makes sense - that's really strange behavior

Comment: "that's really strange behavior" – It really depends on what you expect or want. See "Terminating the tmux session" in [this answer of mine](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/726532/108618). It seems the asker there wanted exactly the default behavior. You want something else, you need to change the option(s). Neither behavior is strange, there are use cases for each.

Comment: it's the same concept as starting an ssh session and trying to run a command, I would expect it to say open like opening a terminal app. If you want to exit immediately, then put "exit x", or use a switch to exist

Answer (score 2):

It's not too clear what layout you are looking for, but here is a demo bash script that may
provide you with some ideas. One problem is that `select-layout even-vertical` will remove any column
structure you have developed, and place *all* the panes vertically. So the approach here is to first create the vertical structure of rows, equalise their spacing, then split each pane horizontally. This image shows
the result. The text shown in each pane is just a hint as to the real command you would run there, and the `aa` `bb` `cc` are just a simplified *pod_name* from your code. Each pane is titled with the `pane_index` which changes all the time, and the `%pane_id` which does not.

[image: xterm tmux layout]

Here is the bash script, which shouldn't be too exotic for MacOS, but you'll have to try for yourself.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
session_uuid=mysession
DISPLAY=:0 xterm -title ttmux -geometry 60x30-1+1 \
  -e "tmux new-session -s $session_uuid  'sleep 20'" &
sleep 2
tmux set -g pane-border-status bottom
tmux set -g pane-border-format "#{pane_index} #{pane_id}"

declare -a names
for pod_name in aa bb cc
do      names+=($pod_name)
done

declare -A pane_ids
for pod_name in ${names[@]}
do      tmux split-window -v -t "$session_uuid" "echo kubectl logs '$pod_name';sleep 999"
        pane_ids[$pod_name]=$(tmux display -p '#{pane_id}')
done

tmux kill-pane -t "$session_uuid:0.0"
tmux select-layout even-vertical # removes columns!

for pod_name in ${names[@]}
do      pane_id=${pane_ids[$pod_name]}
        tmux split-window -h -t "$pane_id" "echo 'Second Column' $pod_name;sleep 999"
        tmux display-panes
done
```

The script starts by creating a new terminal to run tmux with a dummy command, just so it is
easy to see the progress. In the first `for` loop, the bash array `names` is used to collect the `pod_name`, as in the loop in your script. The second `for` loop creates a new vertical pane, and "runs" the "kubectl" command. It retrieves the unique `pane_id` and saves it in the bash associative array `pane_ids`, using the `pod_name` as key.

We then kill the dummy pane, and spread the panes out evenly with `select-layout even-vertical`.
The final `for` loop splits each pane horizontally, using the pod_name and unique pane_id, and "runs" some other command.

Comment: thanks, did you link to the bash script? I dont see a link

Comment: The script is in the post...